# mongo group function for grouping all

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, grouping, aggregation-framework

I want to group all docs returned from a `cond:{condition}` in a mongodb `group`.I use the below code:

```
 db.windows.group({
     key: {usages:0},
     cond: {price:{$lt:30}},
     initial: {'counter':0},
     reduce: function(doc,o){ o.counter++ },
     finalize: function(o) { 
         o.usages.forEach(function(use){ o[use] = use})
     } 
 })
```

But this obviously does not do what I want. Is there a way to pass `all` argument to the `key` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) instead. It uses native coded operators rather than JavaScript and does not require all the "hoop jumping" that `.group()` does:

```js
db.windows.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "price": { "$lt": 30 } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The `null` value on `$group` "_id", means to just group everything which has been retrieved from the initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)  query. The [`"$sum": 1`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum) is effectively a count.